# trying to extract values from the same attribute name from full XML files but only gets 1st line value

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python and XML.
attaching my code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import glob
def extract_points(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    pointss = list()
    for pnts in root.findall('.//shapes/points'):
        pt1 = float(pnts.find('row').text)
        pt2 = float(pnts.find('row1').text)
        coors = [pt1,pt2]
        pointss.append(coors)
    height = int(root.find('.//imageHeight').text)
    width = int(root.find('.//imageWidth').text)
    return pointss,height,width



 txtfiles = []
    for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/xmlfiles/*.xml"):
        txtfiles.append(file)
    for f in txtfiles:
       pointss,height,width = extract_points(f)
```

part of my XML file is:

PYTH

when i run the code only get first row value instead of both rows under the tag point.
i want both the values to be a part of [[1019.2222222222223,304.974358974359 ]] but i only get [1019.2222222222223]. need help plz

Comment: Please add an example of the xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<root>

<version>3.16.2</version>

<flags/>


-<shapes>

<label>m1</label>

<line_color/>

<fill_color/>


-<points>

<row>1019.2222222222223</row>

<row1>304.974358974359</row1>

</points>


-<points>

<row>1035.4615384615386</row>

<row1>331.4700854700855</row1>

</points>


-<points>

<row>1034.6068376068376</row>

<row1>364.8034188034188</row1>

</points>

Comment: @balderman here is the example of XML

Comment: The xml you have added is not a valid one. Please upload a valid XML as part of the question. You can use tools like https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ in order to make sure the xml is valid.

Comment: thank you so much @balderman. I am going to upload valid XML file plz check

Comment: Just let us know when a valid XML is added to the question body.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <version>3.16.2</version>
  <flags/>
  <shapes>
    <label>m1</label>
    <line_color/>
    <fill_color/>
    <points>
      <row>1019.2222222222223</row>
      <row>304.974358974359</row>
    </points>
    <points>
      <row>1035.4615384615386</row>
      <row>331.4700854700855</row>
    </points>
    <points>
      <row>1034.6068376068376</row>
      <row>364.8034188034188</row>
    </points><shape_type>polygon</shape_type>
    <flags/>
  </shapes>
  <lineColor>255</lineColor>
</root>

Comment: there is no **imageHeight** in your xml but there is one in the code ...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <root> <version>3.16.2</version> <flags/> <shapes> <label>m1</label> <line_color/> <fill_color/> <points> <row>1019.2222222222223</row> <row>304.974358974359</row> </points> <points> <row>1035.4615384615386</row> <row>331.4700854700855</row> </points> <shape_type>polygon</shape_type> <flags/> </shapes> <lineColor>255</lineColor><imageHeight>720</imageHeight>
  <imageWidth>1280</imageWidth> </root>

Comment: Sorry but here due to the limit i could not upload complete XML file.

Comment: The code works - check my answer.

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer.https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your xml here is working code

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def extract_points(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    points = list()
    for points_ele in root.findall('.//points'):
        points.append([])
        for row in points_ele:
            points[-1].append(float(row.text))

    height = int(root.find('.//imageHeight').text)
    width = int(root.find('.//imageWidth').text)
    return points, height, width


print(extract_points('data.xml'))
```